# Change Directory in Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch, script, parameters

Based on some other answers I found, I can loop through available drive labels. However, I can't seem to change to that drive:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
%%x
dir
)
```

Which gives me:

```
PS C:\> .\something.bat

C:\>for /F "skip=1 delims=" %x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
%x
 dir
)

C:\>(
 :
 dir
)
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CE0-91A0

 Directory of C:\

07/14/2018  09:54 AM             1,586 compact-all.bat
06/25/2018  01:03 PM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
07/14/2018  08:03 AM    <DIR>          Fraps
06/25/2018  01:07 PM    <DIR>          Intel
06/25/2018  02:18 PM    <DIR>          NVIDIA
04/11/2018  05:38 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
07/13/2018  08:32 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
07/13/2018  04:56 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
06/25/2018  02:12 PM    <DIR>          Python27
07/14/2018  12:26 PM             7,404 result.txt
07/14/2018  12:26 PM                83 something.bat
06/25/2018  01:08 PM    <DIR>          Users
06/30/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               3 File(s)          9,073 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  84,364,111,872 bytes free

C:\>(
 :
 dir
)
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CE0-91A0

 Directory of C:\

07/14/2018  09:54 AM             1,586 compact-all.bat
06/25/2018  01:03 PM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
07/14/2018  08:03 AM    <DIR>          Fraps
06/25/2018  01:07 PM    <DIR>          Intel
06/25/2018  02:18 PM    <DIR>          NVIDIA
04/11/2018  05:38 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
07/13/2018  08:32 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
07/13/2018  04:56 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
06/25/2018  02:12 PM    <DIR>          Python27
07/14/2018  12:26 PM             7,404 result.txt
07/14/2018  12:26 PM                83 something.bat
06/25/2018  01:08 PM    <DIR>          Users
06/30/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               3 File(s)          9,073 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  84,364,111,872 bytes free

C:\>(
 :
 dir
)
The device is not ready.
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CE0-91A0

 Directory of C:\

07/14/2018  09:54 AM             1,586 compact-all.bat
06/25/2018  01:03 PM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
07/14/2018  08:03 AM    <DIR>          Fraps
06/25/2018  01:07 PM    <DIR>          Intel
06/25/2018  02:18 PM    <DIR>          NVIDIA
04/11/2018  05:38 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
07/13/2018  08:32 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
07/13/2018  04:56 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
06/25/2018  02:12 PM    <DIR>          Python27
07/14/2018  12:26 PM             7,404 result.txt
07/14/2018  12:26 PM                83 something.bat
06/25/2018  01:08 PM    <DIR>          Users
06/30/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               3 File(s)          9,073 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  84,364,111,872 bytes free

C:\>(

 dir
)
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CE0-91A0

 Directory of C:\

07/14/2018  09:54 AM             1,586 compact-all.bat
06/25/2018  01:03 PM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
07/14/2018  08:03 AM    <DIR>          Fraps
06/25/2018  01:07 PM    <DIR>          Intel
06/25/2018  02:18 PM    <DIR>          NVIDIA
04/11/2018  05:38 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
07/13/2018  08:32 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
07/13/2018  04:56 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
06/25/2018  02:12 PM    <DIR>          Python27
07/14/2018  12:26 PM             7,404 result.txt
07/14/2018  12:26 PM                83 something.bat
06/25/2018  01:08 PM    <DIR>          Users
06/30/2018  02:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               3 File(s)          9,073 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  84,364,111,872 bytes free
PS C:\>
```

But what I want is it to go to drive c:, d:, etc. and run a command.

I know normally I could do something like

```
dir %%x
```

but I'm making a script to compress (compact) the contents of every drive, but it doesn't seem to take the parameter correctly as it doesn't go through all the files when I do:

```
compact d:
```

which only affect the root of d:

versus

```
d:
compact
```

which affects every file and directory on d:

Comment: First wmic output to console has a flaw supplying line endings cr/cr/lf instead of the usual cr/lf. This can be accounted for. 2nd compact without arguments **shows** the compression ratio of the current dir and it's files - and does nothing else. See `compact /?` or view http://ss64.com/nt/compact.html

Comment: All the "compact" statements (especially the 2nd one) are shortened for brevity. I do have a set of parameters to append to them.

Answer (score 2):

### Change to Drive Letter

To change to a specific drive letter while the command prompt directory is using a different drive letter than the one you need to change to, simply use the `/D` parameter with the [CD](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) command (e.g. `CD /D <DriveLetter>:`) to change to a different drive letter before running proceeding commands.

---

### Delims

You should omit using the `delims="` in the **FOR** loop as that tells it that space is not a delimiter which is not what you want to prevent that `cr/cr/lf` issue as per the [LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings) comment.

- **`FOR /?`**

  > ```
  >     delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
  >                       default delimiter set of space and tab.
  > ```

Since it states the **default delimiter set of space and tab** when you put `delims="` just like that with the ending double quote after the equal sign `="`, that tells it there are no delimiters now.

---

### Compact

Since [Compact](https://ss64.com/nt/compact.html) runs against files in the directory without specifying the path in an argument, if applicable, you can first `CD /D <Letter>:` and then run `Compact /C` to compact all files in a directory, or `Compact /C /S` to compact all files and folders recursively in the directory.

---

### Batch Script

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    CD /D %%x
    Compact /C /S
    <Next or other command>
    )
```

> **Note:** The drive letter is listed in a `<letter>:` format *e.g. `H:`*. So `CD /D H:` works just fine. You will obviously add the `\` to the end of the iterated `%%x` *i.e. `%%x\`* if you need to append a path to use a full path (`%%x\folder\path`) as a command argument *e.g. `dir %%x\folder\path`*.
>
> > [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [CD](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  > ```
  >  Key
  >    /D : change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.
  > ```
- [Compact](https://ss64.com/nt/compact.html)

  > ```
  > Key    
  >    /C        Compress the specified files.  Directories will be marked
  >              so that files added afterward will be compressed.
  >
  >    /S        Perform the specified operation on files in the given
  >              directory and all subdirectories.  
  >              Default "dir" is the current directory.
  > ```
- [I need a .bat for compact.exe and ignoring file types?](https://superuser.com/questions/1336777/i-need-a-bat-for-compact-exe-and-ignoring-file-types/1336797#1336797)

Answer (score 0):

#### However, I can't seem to change to that drive

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem skip=1 to remove the header
rem findstr to remove blank lines
for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do (
  cd /d %%d\
  dir
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Replace `dir` with the command you want to run on the root of each drive.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CD Change Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [WMIC - Windows Management - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)